# Locate an fill input element with selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm Trying to fill the next txtBox but I'have tried with the xpath, name, class.

```
<input name="txtNumDoc" type="text" id="txtNumDoc" class="txtBox">
```

But always get me the same error.

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(.,'txtNumDoc')]"}
```

Comment: There could be several reasons for this error.  Could you provide the complete html or a link it?

Comment: [link](https://www.adres.gov.co/BDUA/Consulta-Afiliados-BDUA) this is the page, is to fill the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the element you are trying to access is inside an iframe so you need to switch to that first:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("iframeBDUA")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

and then you can find your element:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("txtNumDoc")
```

Comment: I think you typo'd the # in the ID... I'm assuming you were thinking CSS selector.

Comment: @JeffC You're right.  Thanks!  I usually use CSS selector 90%+ of the time and was running on auto pilot.  Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

`//*[contains(.,'txtNumDoc')]` is not a valid xpath for this element as we don't have text `txtNumDoc` for this element. `txtNumDoc` is attribute value for both name and id in this case.

use the below.

```
//input[@id="txtNumDoc"]
```

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="txtNumDoc"]')` 
That also gets error:
`Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"//input[@id="txtNumDoc"]"}`

Comment: if you are using `id` method then please send `textNumDoc`.